# MySQL: How do you set the "master" row of a self reference table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

- How do you specify the first row?
- Is `set FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS  = 0` the best idea?
- How do you handle inconsistency of this approach?

```
CREATE TABLE people (
  id        INT PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN   KEY (id) REFERENCES people (id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
  id        INT PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES people(id)
);
```

`NULL` is a typical way to express that something has no parent -- which is presumably what you mean by "master".